# Jest Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `url` supplied to `Favicon`, expected one of type [string]

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

When testing the AppRouter component, I get the error shown below.

I think it has to do with the fact that Jest cannot understand the prop the Favicon component has and I have to configure Jest to ignore that somehow.

My initial thoughts are configuring the moduleNameMapper option in the jest config but tried putting 'url' there and that did not work.

Any thoughts on this?

Error:
[image]

`jest.config.js`

```
const ignores = ['/node_modules/', '<rootDir>/src/__tests__/__mocks__'];

module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest', 
    roots: ['<rootDir>'],
    modulePaths: [
        "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    moduleDirectories: [
        "node_modules",
    ],
    transformIgnorePatterns: [...ignores],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest',
        '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest',
        '^.+\\.(gif|svg|ico|url)$': '<rootDir>/svgTransform.js',
    },
    testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.js?$',
    moduleFileExtensions: ['tsx', 'js', 'ts'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "\\.(css|less|scss|sass|ico|url)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
        '\\.(png|jpg|webp|ttf|woff|woff2|svg|mp4|url)$': '<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
      },
    clearMocks: true,
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect', './src/tests/setup.js'],
    resolver: 'jest-webpack-resolver',
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    // collectCoverage: true, // todo
    // coverageDirectory: "coverage",  // todo
}
```

The component being tested:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useState } from 'react'

import useLocalStorage from './hooks/useLocalStorage'
import * as Constants from './constants'

import Header from './layout/header/header'
import MainPage from './pages/mainPage/mainPage'
import PostPage from './pages/postPage/postPage'
import UserPage from './pages/userPage/userPage'
import LoginPage from './pages/loginPage/loginPage'
import SignupPage from './pages/signupPage/signupPage'
import NewPage from './pages/newPage/newPage'
import FeedbackPage from './pages/feedbackPage/feedbackPage'
import AdminPage from './pages/adminPage/adminPage'
import SettingPage from './pages/settingPage/settingPage'

import { WebContext } from './context/WebContext'
import Favicon from 'react-favicon'

const AppRouter = () => {
    const [adminCode, setAdminCode] = useLocalStorage('admin', '')
    const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false)
    const [page, setPage] = useState(Constants.Page.Home)

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Favicon url={require('../public/favicon.ico')} />
                <WebContext.Provider
                    value={{
                        isMenuOpen,
                        setIsMenuOpen,
                        page,
                        setPage,
                        adminCode,
                        setAdminCode,
                    }}
                >
                    <Header />
                    <h1>
                        hello
                    </h1>

                    <Switch>
                        <Route component={MainPage} path="/" exact={true} />
                        <Route component={PostPage} path="/post/:id" />
                        <Route component={UserPage} path="/user" />
                        <Route component={LoginPage} path="/login" />
                        <Route component={SignupPage} path="/signup" />
                        <Route component={NewPage} path="/new" />
                        <Route component={FeedbackPage} path="/feedback" />
                        <Route component={AdminPage} path="/admin" />
                        <Route component={SettingPage} path="/setting" />
                        <Route component={() => <Redirect to="/" />} />
                    </Switch>
                </WebContext.Provider>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default AppRouter
```

Test:

```
import { render, userEvent as user, screen, getByRole } from '@testing-library/react'
import { Router, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import AppRouter from '../router'

test('Renders AppRouter', () => {
    render(<AppRouter />)

    screen.debug()
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would be interesting in hearing more thoughts on what people are doing with their transform files.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this error by adding `require` in my `transform` option in the `jest.config.js` file.

For posterity, here is the `svgTransform.js` file that I am using in this project:

```
// This code resolves Jest errors when testing components that have SVG images.
// Specified in the Jest config file under "transform" options.
module.exports = {
    process() {
        return {
            code: 'module.exports = {};',
        }
    },
    getCacheKey() {
        return 'svgTransform'
    },
}
```

Comment: Would be interesting in hearing more thoughts on what people are doing with their transform files.